# What post query does Stack Overflow fire to get a question's details with answers, tags, votes, etc.?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, data-explorer, sql

As I was reading to get a question or post below, a query may be fired by Stack Overflow:

```
SELECT * # Replace the actual fields
FROM posts
WHERE (Id = {POST_ID}) OR (ParentId = {POST_ID})
ORDER BY PostTypeId ASC, Score DESC
```

The above query will give the POSTS table only. What about other data?

So here isn't any join in the query. When a post gets its a combination of question, comments, votes in question, votes in answer, user details, etc., which exact query is fired for getting these details?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede)

Comment: @RobertLongson Sorry but its giving table details. i am looking for SQL query.

Comment: Once you have table details you can just write the SQL for whatever you want.

Answer (score 4):

All the other data is stored in different tables. So you would not run one query, but several.

For example, to get comments for a given Post you would execute this query:

```
SELECT * # Replace the actual fields
FROM comments 
WHERE (PostId = {POST_ID}) 
ORDER BY CreationDate ASC
```

and for Up Votes, this query (maybe combine with down votes, that are have VoteTypeId = 3):

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM Votes 
WHERE (PostId = {POST_ID}) 
AND VoteTypeId = 2
```

and for the  data in the usercard for a Post, join the Posts and Users table:

```
SELECT Users.* # Replace the actual fields
FROM Users
INNER JOIN Posts ON Posts.OwnerUserId = Users.Id 
WHERE (PostId = {POST_ID})
```

Alternatively you could [create a query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1234491) that does a left outer join of Posts, Users, Votes and Comments but that will give you a lot of columns in your resultset and a lot of duplicated data, even for a single post.  Not very useful.

```
select *
from Posts P
left outer join comments c on c.postid = p.id
left outer join users pu on pu.id = p.owneruserid
left outer join votes v on v.postid = p.id
where p.id = 4
```

On Stack Overflow I expect that for a single question the Page Controller will build a View model by getting data from several components that will run very specific query to only get that data that is now needed. If you want to get an global but somewhat simplified idea how this will work on an SE site, look the code of the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/tree/master/App/StackExchange.DataExplorer). It is build by some of the SE developers so I assume they borrowed the parts of the SE software architecture that they knew would work. Alternatively look at the blog of [Nick Craver](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2016/02/03/stack-overflow-a-technical-deconstruction/) (or his [tweets](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver)) to get a glimpse of the internal code base of Stack Overflow. If you're more curious about tricky SQL Server Database Administration stories on Stack Overflow databases do check [the blog from the awesome bluefeeted Taryn](https://www.tarynpivots.com/).

Keep in mind that the source code of Stack Overflow is not open source. We have to do it with the bits and pieces that are leaked by SE developers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer..So how Stackoverflow DB resolve this issue? See when user click on Individual question all data loads for a individual question so they will fire multiple query to load the data or one query with JOIN?

Comment: @subodh We don’t know how SO does it. They are a private company and we are merely their users. We only know what they’ve made public, and that’s SEDE. They haven’t, and have no reason to, publish all the technical details of their architecture. You have SEDE; the rest is up to you.